# Integral without using Euler substitution

Tags: calculus, integration

Help me please with integral:
$$\int \frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^{2}-x+1}}{x-1}\;dx$$

I must solve it without using  Euler substitution.

Thanks!

Comment: What is Euler substitution?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: In this case ($a>0$) the Euler substitution is $\sqrt{ax^2+bx+c}=t-x\sqrt{a}$. See Springer Encyclopedia of Mathematics, [Euler substitutions](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Euler_substitutions).

Comment: I deleted my wrong answer, because I was not able to find a correct solution.

Comment: No trig substitutions either?

Comment: Is it solvable by Euler substitution? I can't solve it at all...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: writing 
$$\frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{x-1}=\frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{x-1}\frac{2x+\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{2x+\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}},$$
we find $$\frac{2x-\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}{x-1}=\frac{4x^2-(4x^2-x+1)}{(x-1)(2x+\sqrt{4x^2-x+1})}=\frac 1{2x+\sqrt{4x^2-x+1}}.$$

Comment: I think I see a couple mistakes here. In the first line, if we're rationalizing the numerator, there's a sign error where the denominator should be $2x + \sqrt{4x^2 - x + 1}$, and in the second line the $2x$ term seems to have disappeared from the denominator completely. The end result should be $\frac{1}{2x + \sqrt{4x^2 - x + 1}}$, but I think this ruins the approach expanded upon by @Américo Tavares.

Comment: @lewist: Yes, it ruins. I am not able to find a new valid solution.